# Microsoft Outlook Authentication using react js and AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, outlook

I am new to Amazon AWS and I wish to implement Microsoft outlook authentication with react js. Seems no resources are available on this subject. I will be very grateful if someone can walk me through it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "Microsoft outlook authentication"?

Comment: basically having users sign in to your app using their microsoft outlook account

Comment: See [Authenticate a user with a single-sign-on token in an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/authenticate-a-user-with-an-sso-token).